# Joint probability distribution of vector lengths

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-variables

Suppose we have $J$ random vectors $\{{\bf X}_1, \ldots, {\bf X}_J\}$ where each vector ${\bf X}_j \sim N_K({\bf 0}_K, {\bf I}_K), (j = 1,\ldots, J)$ is independent and identically distributed as per the standard $K$-variate normal distribution with zero mean and identity variance-covariance matrix. Let $Y_j = \sqrt{{\bf X}_j^\top {\bf X}_j}$ denote the length of the $j$-th vector. Since the vectors ${\bf X}_j$ are i.i.d., the joint distribution of the lengths $\{Y_1,\ldots,Y_J\}$ is

\begin{equation}
p(Y_1, \ldots, Y_J) = \prod_{j=1}^J f(Y_j ; K)
\end{equation}

where $f(Y_j ; K)$ is the probability density function of a Chi random variable with $K$ degrees of freedom.

Now, suppose another $J$ mutually orthogonal vectors are constructed such that

\begin{equation}
\sum_{j=1}^J {\bf X}_j {\bf X}_j^\top = \sum_{j=1}^J {\bf A}_j {\bf A}_j^\top, \quad {\bf A}_s^\top {\bf A}_{t \neq s} = 0
\end{equation}

Let $a_j = \sqrt{{\bf A}_j^\top {\bf A}_j}$ denote the length of the $j$-th vector ${\bf A}_j$. What is the joint distribution of the lengths of $\{{\bf A}_1, \ldots, {\bf A}_J\}$ ?

From (3.2) in [http://www.allisons.org/ll/Images/People/Wallace/Multi-Factor/], the joint distribution of the lengths is

\begin{equation}
p(a_1, \ldots, a_J) = \prod_{i=1}^J f(a_i ; K) \prod_{i < j}^J \frac{|a_j^2 - a_i^2|}{a_j a_i}
\end{equation}

which is the original Chi distribution times an "adjustment factor". If anyone can give me a hint or a reference as to how this density was derived, it would be greatly appreciated. I looked at the reference in the above URL (Muirhead, 1982, p.107) but that talks about the joint density of eigenvalues of a Wishart distribution and I am not really sure how the two are connected.